# Converting Recurision to Iteration

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

How would I convert this code to use while loops instead of recursion?

```
void game(void)
{
    int answer;
    printf("%s", Questions[level]);
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (level < 8) {
        if (is_right(level, answer)) {
            printf("Good Job!\n");
            level += 1;
            game();
        }
        else {

            printf("Sorry, you got the wrong answer. Try Again! \n");

            sleep(1);
            system("clear");
            level = 0;

            game();
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Great Job, You Won!");
    }
}
```

I tried starting with a while loop and trying to work backwards, but I got lost in the sea of code

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of strange things in your program that I'll get back to later, but to start with, let's focus on the question:

> How would I convert this code to use while loops instead of recursion?

There are many ways to do that...

The current recursive calls, i.e. `game();`, takes no arguments, nor does it use a return value. So a very simple way to get rid of recursion and keeping the exact same functionality could be:

1. Add a `while(1)` loop around all the existing code
2. Replace the current recursive calls with a `continue;` statement
3. Add a `break;` statement when the loop is to terminate

That would look like:

```
void game(void)
{
    while(1) {        // Add a while loop
        int answer;
        printf("%s", Questions[level]);
        scanf("%d", &answer);
        if (level < 8) {
            if (is_right(level, answer)) {
                printf("Good Job!\n");
                level += 1;
                // game();
                continue;  // Start a new round of the game
            }
            else {

                printf("Sorry, you got the wrong answer. Try Again! \n");

                sleep(1);
                system("clear");
                level = 0;

                //game();
                continue;  // Start a new round of the game
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Great Job, You Won!");

            break; // End the game by breaking out of the while loop
                   // This could also be a return; statement
        }
    }
}
```

The above solution preserves the structure of the original program. If we allow some (minor) restructuring, we can do a little better.

```
void game(void)
{
    while(1) {
        int answer;
        printf("%s", Questions[level]);
        scanf("%d", &answer);

        // Check if the game has finished
        if (level >= 8) {
            printf("Great Job, You Won!");
            return;  // or break;
        }

        if (is_right(level, answer)) {
            printf("Good Job!\n");
            level += 1;
        } else {
            printf("Sorry, you got the wrong answer. Try Again! \n");
            sleep(1);
            system("clear");
            level = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of checking for "shall game continue" the above version checks for "has game finished" and - if so - it returns. By doing that we no longer need the explicit `continue;` statements.

Now getting back to the "strange" things in your program:

1. When a user wins the game (i.e. `level` reach 8), the code will still ask one more question and once the answer has been entered, the program finish. **That is probably not intended...**
2. Further, the only way to finish the game is to win the game (i.e. answer correct a number of times in a row). I would expect a way for the user to say "I give up"

Finally there is a serious problem with your code that may lead to errors like program crash or infinite loop. Always check the return value of `scanf`! (*see end-note*)

Fixing those things and doing a little more restructuring could lead to a program like:

```
void game(void)
{
    level = 0;   // Assuming a new game always starts a level zero

    while(1) {
        int answer;
        printf("%s", Questions[level]);
        if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1) {
            // Wrong input or input error

            // Add error handling... but for now, just terminate
            exit(1);
        }

        // Let the user end the program with a negative input
        if (answer < 0) {
            printf("Sorry to see you leave before finishing the game. Bye.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        if (is_right(level, answer)) {
            printf("Good Job!\n");
            level += 1;

            // Check if the game has finished
            if (level == 8) {
                printf("Great Job, You Won!");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            printf("Sorry, you got the wrong answer. Try Again! \n");
            sleep(1);
            system("clear");
            level = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

*End-note:*

While it's true that the return value from `scanf` shall be checked, the better advice would be:

**Never use** `scanf`.

At the surface `scanf` looks like an easy way to get user input but the truth is that it has so many pitfalls that only real experts are able to use it (and they probably won't). The number of SO questions where (incorrect use of) `scanf` is the root cause of a problem is extreme. And they keep coming...

So forget that you ever heard about `scanf`. If you do like the features of `scanf`, you will (nearly) always do better by using `fgets` followed by `sscanf`.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to call it recursion.

```
void game(void)
{
    int answer;

    while (level < 8) 
    {
        printf("%s", Questions[level]);
        if(scanf("%d", &answer) != 1){ /* handle error */}        
        if (is_right(level, answer)) 
        {
            printf("Good Job!\n");
            level += 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Sorry, you got the wrong answer. Try Again! \n");
            sleep(1);
            system("clear");
            level = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Great Job, You Won!");
}
```

Comment: This code is not doing exactly the same as the code in the question

Comment: @SupportUkraine what is different?

Comment: The original code sets `level` to zero only in the "wrong answer" branch.  It prints a question and reads an answer on every call to `game()`, regardless of the value of `level` on entry (so it eventually reads one answer that it doesn't check).  Probably these both represent errors in the original code, in which case the code presented in this answer corrects them, but that nevertheless means that the code here is not altogether equivalent to the OP's recursive version.

Comment: See what happens when `level` reach the value 8